# How can I solve FireBase database forbidden characters in Key or a workaround

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, google-places-api

I have this FireBase database structure an really would love to have the key like this example:

```
"US": {
    "name": "United States",
    "PATH_TO_STREETS": {
        "US/California/Orange County/Orange/3138 E Maple Ave": "-K1234567"
        "US/California/Orange County/Orange/3139 E Maple Ave": "-K12334rt"
        "US/California/Orange County/Orange/3140 E Maple Ave": "-K1234r34"
     },
 }
```

Because the key is unique it´s a really good idea if it wasn't for the Firebase forbidden database characters:

```
. (period)    
$ (dollar sign)    
[ (left square bracket)    
] (right square bracket)    
 (hash or pound sign)    
/ (forward slash)
```

The `California` path that the above key consist of comes from Google Places api, and I wonder if any more of the forbidden database characters can pop up, and how to counteract this from blowing up when a future key have a # or $.

I also need a way to work with this key like:

```
String[] split = theKey.split("/");
```

If I replace the (forward slash) what should I use, or how can a do this in another way maybe. Does Google Places api´s autocomplete result have any of the forbidden database characters?

I could do like:

```
// test for . $ # [ ] / and replace them
public static String removeInvalidChars(String text) {
    text = text.replace(".", "");
    text = text.replace("$", "");
    text = text.replace("#", "");
    text = text.replace("[", "");
    text = text.replace("]", "");
    text = text.replace("/", "");
    return text;
}
```

With this `removeInvalidChars` it will blow up I think, feels like I loose control over the key structure:

```
"US/California/Orange County/Orange/3138 E Maple Ave"
```

Maybe should I create s separate root node where a hash version of the above path is stored. Then I save the Hashes like :

```
"US": {
    "name": "United States",
    "HASH_TO_STREETS": {
        "sadsasasjkinIGhGVBJKHBHIUOuijHdBJLI": "US/California/Orange County/Orange/3138 E Maple Ave",
        "KJHGjgh67HGCFhgvhjbIuiokkBHJbkjhBkj": "US/California/Orange County/Orange/3139 E Maple Ave",
        "LKJHNJHKHky7y78gHGHGJ675JHJHdbHJBjh":  "US/California/Orange County/Orange/3139 E Maple Ave"
     },
 }
```

Hey maybe that´s the answer...mm what do you think?

Comment: Silly but could work. I noticed you are replacing special chars with empty spaces, how about replacing them with for example: `text = text.replace("$", "(dollar-sign)");` and on the other end `text = text.replace("(dollar-sign)", "$");`. Yes, it occupies more memory in the database.

Comment: Either replace the invalid chars with a known value, so you can recreate the keys, or, better yet, remove all this duplication by using the keys as a path, so under 'US' you'll have states 'California'... then counties, cities, and finally a list of streets.

Comment: @323go I actually did that to start with but it soon accord to me that setting databas rules would be hard, and dnormalization was needed, welcomed. The "(dollar-sign)") is not bad but still tampering with this path will blow up maybe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most developers store encoded values in the keys. The most common one is when storing email addresses, in which case they escape the `.` in the email address with a `,`.

```
"puf@firebaseui,com": true
```

In your case I see two main options:

1. Encoded the offending characters in the key.
2. Filter the offending characters from the key.

Filtering is definitely simpler, but is non-reversible: you can never get the exact value back from the key in that case.

Encoding is reversible. For example: we could get the email address back from the previous example by converting the `,` back into a `.`. Since a `,` can never occur in an email address, the conversion is lossless and reversible

Comment: Thanks for your Super in sites as usual

Answer (score 0):

A nice workaround could be:

```js
const encode=s=>encodeURIComponent(s).replace('.', '%2E');
const decode=s=>decodeURIComponent(s);
```

`encodeURIComponent` and `decodeURIComponent` are native js functions. Unfortunately the encoding skips `.` so you have to manually convert it to corresponding ascii code. However, the nice thing is that you don't have to worry about the decode counterpart because any given ascii code can be decoded correctly.

Usage:

```js
let key_to_firebase = encode(key);
let key = decode(key_to_firebase);
```